ValueError: unconverted data remains: 1
Пытаюсь получить данные из dbf файла таким способом:
from dbf_light import Dbf

with Dbf.open('POST_PR.DBF') as dbf:
    for field in dbf.fields:
        print('Поле: %s' % field)
    for rows in dbf:
        print(str(rows[0]))

При запуске программы происходит ошибка:

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 1

Даже при выводе одного столбца, который состоит из цифр не могу ничего вывести. Поля выводятся. Проблема в том, что у меня данные помеченные красным. Как я понял - это пометка удаления(или что-то вроде этого). Подскажите, как удалить тогда эти данные полностью?
